# Can it be destructive to disallow all MediaWiki:Special pages in robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, content, mediawiki, categories

I consider preventing indexation of all of MediaWiki 1.33.0's ***Special*** pages;
<sub>(In Hebrew, "מיוחד" means "special")</sub>:

```
Disallow: /מיוחד:*
Disallow: /index.php?title=מיוחד:*
Disallow: /index.php%3Ftitle%3D%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93:*
```

Doing so is good in general because many of these pages aren't useful to the avarage surfer (rather to staff only) but some are important to both a regular users and crawlers.
A problem of not indexing "RecentChanges" and "Categories" is plausible though, as both these ***Special*** pages serve as "small, dynamic pseudo-sitemaps" that give access to virtually all webpages in the site.

Would you remove `Disallow` of MediaWiki special pages from robots.txt altogether?
Would you keep it with a good list exceptions just for "RecentChanges" and "Categories"?
Would you take a totally different approach?

Comment: RecentChanges and Categories are not useful as sitemaps. AllPages, maybe.

Comment: Hi; please consider to elaborate more, thanks...

Comment: They don't actually list all or even most pages of the wiki. RecentChanges might be useful for a search engine if it wants to learn about updates very quickly, but Google won't bother to do that with your wiki.

Comment: I believe at might - but at least not at this point...

Comment: I understand from your comment that Disallowing all ***special*** pages is bad for SEO anyway. But is it okay to keep all of them allowed? Isn't it bad as well?

Comment: I have no idea if it's either good or bad. It's hard to make blanket pronouncements for SEO. You could also disable special pages and run [`generateSitemap.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:GenerateSitemap.php) periodically. Still no idea if that would be good though; you should track your own metrics and evaluate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaWiki.org includes this in [their robots.txt file](https://www.mediawiki.org/robots.txt):

```
Disallow: /wiki/Special:
Disallow: /wiki/Spezial:
Disallow: /wiki/Spesial:
Disallow: /wiki/Special%3A
Disallow: /wiki/Spezial%3A
Disallow: /wiki/Spesial%3A
```

Comment: So presumably if that do it it isn't horrible practice.